# How do I finish the first level in No Heroes Allowed?

Tags: no-heroes-allowed

I need help, I can't even finish the first level of No heroes allowed. I don't think I understand how the game works. At the third stage I always lose, I can't seem to surround Badman with enough monsters.

Answer (score 2):

First of all do the basic training, including the advanced ones advanced ones. They'll show you some nice tricks you can do. If you've also done that then try this; use the water a lot. It's a great handicap you can use earlier on and later as a buffer zone, seeing as it automatically replenishes itself.

As to how to use it as a buffer, try making a few twists and turns to cut off the water and then dig up and out, then make another area to put your overlord in. With this you'll be able to have the water be the path to badman, yet if they get through it will have fully restored itself when they come back through with badman.

Some other advice could be to try to rush the few first heroes by summoning them early (hit the door they come through with your pickaxe) and build up you dig power. Don't spend too much early on and when you hit waves 3-4 of heroes you'll have over 1k to spend on upgrades for your monsters (in case you didn't know, the amount of time ti take to kill them, your overall horde strength, and leftover dig power effect how much more you'll get for the next wave, aka, preform efficiently, and get rewarded well). As a personal suggestion, hold back on trying to mutate your monsters until after you've gotten some basic upgrades, that way you can pay a lower fee to get a just as strong monster.

If you're having trouble with dip power, just try planning out how you'll dig before hacking away so you can be more efficient. It also helps if you make large circulating areas so slimes and whatnot will continue to wander around and repopulate areas the heroes already went through without you having to waste dig power spawning more.

If that hasn't done it for you, I could only suggest trying your damnedest to get a dragon in a good area and us the stat boosts the rune born monsters provide. One more thing about rune monsters, if you manage to get a rune with high mana and low nutrients (3 is the max you can have as far as I can tell) and have a hero walk over it and deplete their mana while draining the mana from the rune, eventually it will change into a Mara rune. These are hard to get, but the Mara is one of the strongest monsters in the game and could be a massive boon.